# C# best way to store multiple column mysql query in a list then access each part of query

Tags: c#

How would I store a query from mysql into a list.

For example, i have column a b c d,

public list ListA {get; set;}

I want to store column a b c d, and then reference it like

```
foreach(string here in ListA)
{ string columna = list[0];
string columnab = list[1];}
```

hope that makes some

Comment: It all depends on how the data is being accessed, naturally. However, care should be taken (e.g. with DataReader) to make sure to only access the resource during the appropriate *lifetime*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to do it would be to create a class like this

```
class Item
{
    public string A {get; set;}
    public string B {get; set;}
    public string C {get; set;}
    public string D {get; set;}
}
```

and store and iterate over a `List<Item>`